# data Grid Data bound field header text change in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, boundfield, headertext

I have a datagrid that has a BoundColumn there I am trying to change the header text on page load I so fa. I have tried this.

```
  <asp:datagrid id="dgdata" runat="server" Width="658px" CellPadding="2" PageSize="2" DataKeyField="Name"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" BorderColor="AliceBlue" OnItemDataBound="dgTranscript_ItemDataBound">
          <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"></asp:BoundColumn>
</Columns>
        </asp:datagrid>
```

C#

```
 dgdata.Columns[1].Visible = true;
            dgdata.Columns[1].HeaderText = lblAverage.Text
```

I want to set the text to be the text that's inside that label but its not letting me if i say without the label it works

```
 dgdata.Columns[1].Visible = true;
            dgdata.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Some Text";
```

Binding Data

```
 DataSet ds;
        DataRow drClient = null;
        dgdata.Columns[1].HeaderText = lblAverage.Text; // Here before the Daatabind I set the text to be that label 
        DataConn.WebExecute(out ds); 
        DataConn.Bind(dgTranscript, ds);// This binds the data to the datagrid
```

It shows that text as the header but when I try punting in any string or a label text it denies the whole header disappears
Thanks in advance. Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

If the value of `lblAverage` is set after calling `DataBind` on the datagrid then the header will remain empty.

This works

```
lblAverage.Text = "Some Text";
dgdata.Columns[0].HeaderText = lblAverage.Text;

dgdata.DataSource = mySource;
dgdata.DataBind();
```

While this will not

```
lblAverage.Text = "Some Text";

dgdata.DataSource = mySource;
dgdata.DataBind();

dgdata.Columns[0].HeaderText = lblAverage.Text;
```

Comment: Ok yeah that didn't work. let me put in more info on the question how i am binding it to the data and where i set the headertext

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this.

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblAverage"  runat="server" Text="Header Value"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgdata" runat="server" Width="658px" CellPadding="2" PageSize="2" DataKeyField="Name"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" ShowHeader="true" BorderColor="AliceBlue">
            <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblheader" runat="server" Text='<%# lblAverage.Text %>'></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblvalue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Nope Sir I just want to set the header of that one Column that's on the top not add another row